# gsutil BadRequestException 400 None

Tags: gsutil

i have a request to copy files from AWS S3 bucket to GCS storage with the following command:

```
gsutil -m cp -r ${sourceURL} ${destinationURL}
```

howver, i encountered an error

> BadRequestException: 400 None

and the error message followed is

> CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to solve it?
i check my aws/gs configuration, they are all right.

Comment: Check the api documentation of the services to know what they expect as part of the connection URLs

Answer (score 0):

To use the gsutil tool on S3 buckets check that the S3 [credentials in the boto file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability#using_the_gsutil_command_line) for gsutil are correct and also try using rsync instead of cp.

If you continue having issues you might wanna use the [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview#what-is-storage-transfer).